# complete list of @IB* in xcode and their use cases

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm currently learning iOS development in `swift`.

In xcode, I know the most commonly used `@IB` are `@IBAction` and `@IBOutlet`, there are other `@IB` such as `@IBInspectable`, `@IBDesignable`.

But I was wondering, Is there other `@IB` available and what is their use cases?

Comment: There is one more http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/

Comment: hi @adev, thanks for the link. I have searched a lot of documentation, and the ones that I have mentioned are all I can find. And their are all over the places. Its kind of frustrating that there is no one place where all the `@IB` are collected and explained.

Comment: @adev: There is no `@IBOutletCollection` in Swift. The equivalent to outlet collections can be achieved with `@IBOutlet` and array properties.

Comment: @macmoonshine, Thanks, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are attibutes, and AFAIK There is a no complete list from Apple, but there is an `IDE` [test file in swift repository](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/test/IDE/print_ast_tc_decls.swift), that gather in test all this data for `IB` prefix (probably stands for `Interface Builder`):

#### @IBAction

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/constants/interface_builder_constants/ibaction

> Type qualifier used by Interface Builder to expose a method as a
>   connection point between user interface elements and app code. Used
>   instead of a void return type in a method declaration. For examples of
>   how to use this identifier, see Xcode Overview.

In other words - it's connect your storyboard object like `UIButton` to action that can be performed on it `@IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any)`

#### @IBOutlet

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/constants/interface_builder_constants/iboutlet?language=objc

> Type qualifier used by Interface Builder to expose a symbol as a
>   connection point for sending messages from app code to a user
>   interface element. Used immediately before an object type in a
>   property or instance variable declaration. For examples of how to use
>   this identifier, see Xcode Overview.

In other words - it's something to refer to when you want to change (ex) text in label. `@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!`

#### @IBOutletColection (now it's just [] of @IBOutlet!)

Whenever group of outlets, should have similar (or better - the same!) behaviour and styling you can put it all together under `@IBOutletCollection`. It looks like this: `@IBOutlet var someLabels: [UILabel]!`

---

Both below help with live rendering:

> You can use two different attributes—@IBDesignable and
>   @IBInspectable—to enable live, interactive custom view design in
>   Interface Builder. When you create a custom view that inherits from
>   the UIView class or the NSView class

#### @IBDesignable

> You can add the @IBDesignable
>   attribute just before the class declaration. After you add the custom
>   view to Interface Builder (by setting the custom class of the view in
>   the inspector pane), Interface Builder renders your view in the
>   canvas.

#### @IBinspectable

> You can also add the @IBInspectable attribute to properties with types compatible with user defined runtime attributes. After you add your custom view to Interface Builder, you can edit these properties in the inspector.

[More information you can find here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH5-ID86)

It look in Interface Builder like this:
[image]

---

There is also some other like: `@GKInspectable`, `@NSManaged`,`@nonobjc` , `@available` and so on... You can read more about [attributes in swift here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html)

Answer (score 3):

I think there is no complete and compact list from Apple. But if you look into Apple's iBook *Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C* and look for "@IB", you will find all the attributes with an explanation. You can also find explanations to other attributes like `@NSManaged` or `@objc`.